# How do i change the if statement to iterate backwards through the array?

Tags: java, arrays

How do I iterate backwards through the array? What do I need to do to the `for` statement?

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int a[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
    for (int i=1; i<=a.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("a[i] = " + a[i]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your if statement.. i cant see in your code?

Comment: i assume you mean for statement. start from the back till i>=0 and decrement counter

Comment: If you mean the 'for' statement, you just need to change that to `for (int i=a.length - 1; i >=0; i--)`

Comment: I meant the for statement. Sorry about that

Comment: Thank you very much! that worked like a charm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping through the elements in a array backwards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379489/looping-through-the-elements-in-a-array-backwards)

Answer (score 3):

In case it about traversing the array backwards you can do like this

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int a[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
        for (int i=a.length -1 ; i>=0; i--)
        {
            System.out.println("a[i] = " + a[i]); 
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
a[i] = 3
a[i] = 2
a[i] = 1
a[i] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Start from the length minus one and go back to zero

```
for (int i = a.length -1; a >= 0; i--)
{
    System.out.println("a[i] = " + a[i]); 
}
```