# Is it possible to start the for loop from backwards

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm pretty sure that my logic is right but it doesn't print anything. Can anyone please take a look at my code. It supposes to print the string backward. But it doesn't print anything. It doesn't give me an error either. Thanks

```
String x = input.nextLine();

    for(int i = x.length()-1; i<=0;i--)
   {
   System.out.println(x.charAt(i));

   }
```

Comment: Change `<=` to be `>=`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping through the elements in a array backwards](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9379489/5743988)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<=` vs `>=`. For backward you loop should check `>=`

```
  for(int i = x.length()-1; i<=0;i--)
   {
   System.out.println(x.charAt(i));

   }
```

Should be

```
  for(int i = x.length()-1; i>=0;i--)
   {
   System.out.println(x.charAt(i));

   }
```

Comment: Thanks, so it was a logical error Thanks again