# Printing elements of array called top10 backwards

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to write a code to print the elements of an array called top10 backwards. How would this be? Anything would be great as I have no clue how to begin.

Comment: you start from last 10 by setting initial index = 9, for (var i = array.length-1; i >= 0 ; i--) console.log(array[i])

Comment: You start at `0` and loop to `9` and request the indices in reverse order (ie `top10[top10.length - index - 1]` or you could loop from `9` down to `0` printing each element. Take a look at [The for Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) for more details

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping through the elements in an array backwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379489/looping-through-the-elements-in-an-array-backwards)

Answer (score 0):

It would look something like this:

```
int topTenBackwards[] = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
   for(int i = topTenBackwards.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
                System.out.println(topTenBackwards[i]);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

To reverse an int array, you swap items up until you reach the midpoint, like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < validData.length / 2; i++)
{
    int temp = validData[i];
    validData[i] = validData[validData.length - i - 1];
    validData[validData.length - i - 1] = temp;
}
```

This is taken from another question, here:

[How do I reverse an int array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137755/how-do-i-reverse-an-int-array-in-java)

I think its what you need. You just reverse it, and then iterate and print the first 10, with a function like:

```
    int[] myarray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};

    for (int element: myarray) {
        System.out.println(element);
    }
```

So, endgame should look something like:

```
int[][] myarray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
for(int i = 0; i < myarray.length / 2; i++)
{
    int[] temp = myarray[i];
    myarray[i] = myarray[myarray.length - i - 1];
    myarray[myarray.length - i - 1] = temp;
}
// array reversed
int x = 0;
for (int[] element: myarray) {
    System.out.println(element);
    x++;
    if (x == 10) {
        break;
    }
}
// array printed
```

Using the  `int[] element: myarray`   gives me all the items in the array, and the   `break`   stops the printing loop when you reach the 10th, if you don't, it still stops when you run out of items (like with just 9)

If your array is multi-dimensional you can just nest the for-loops to iterate the inner levels, or use the `Arrays.toString(myarray)` function from `java.util.Arrays;`

Printing arrays taken from: [Java Program to Print an Array - Programiz](https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/examples/print-array)

Hope it helps. (If I made a mistake, I'm happy to be corrected)

Comment: Thank you so much for you help. That helps a lot, my finals in 24 hours so thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing here the code for Printing elements of an array called top10 backward. There are a lot of resource through you find it in a different language like PHP, C++, Python, and all.

```
public class GFG { 
          /* Function to reverse arr[] from  
            start to end*/
            static void rvereseArray(int arr[], 
                            int start, int end) 
            { 
                int temp; 

                while (start < end) 
                { 
                    temp = arr[start];  
                    arr[start] = arr[end]; 
                    arr[end] = temp; 
                    start++; 
                    end--; 
                }  
            }      

            /* Utility that prints out an 
            array on a line */
            static void printArray(int arr[],  
                                    int size) 
            { 
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
                     System.out.print(arr[i] + " "); 

                 System.out.println(); 
            }  

            // Driver code 
            public static void main(String args[]) { 

                int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}; 
                printArray(arr, 6); 
                rvereseArray(arr, 0, 5); 
                System.out.print("Reversed array is \n"); 
                printArray(arr, 6);  

            } 
        }
```

Here I am also suggesting you learn from geeks for geeks, and **[other programming blogs](https://hackr.io/tutorials/learn-java)**.